# How to deal with Iphone 5 retina display check?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, retina-display

When running app in Iphone 5, I discovered that `[UIImage imageNamed]` doesn't detect retina display when it comes to iphone or ipod 5. I have 2 images for everything in my app, the standard one, and the retina one named @2x. Now, I used to select the regular image in storyboard or programmatically because I thought it would get the right image automatically, like simulator does, but turns out, Iphone 5 doesn't. So, for my understanding, I have to manually check if is retina using the code:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
        ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
        // Retina display
        NSLog(@"RETINA");
    } else {
        // non-Retina display
        NSLog(@"NON-RETINA");
    }
```

Now, since I'll be using this code a lot, is there a way to avoid repeating it? Maybe creating a protocol, or even subclassing `UIImage`? I'm not sure how to deal with this, I thought this was done automatically.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, `imageNamed` picks the correct image for the appropriate pixel density.

Comment: It works perfectly when I run on simulator with retina display, but when I run on my iphone, it doesn't pick the right image, it picks the image with lower resolution, as if my iphone 5 didn't have retina display. I'm not sure why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: If it works on the 4inch simulator, I would suggest you do a clean build of the app on your device to make sure that the resources are actually being copied.

Comment: Are you including the file extension in the image name (e.g. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]`)?

Comment: You only need to remove the image folder and clean the project and then again import both images for standard image.png and image@2x.png for retina. Device will automatically detect right image according to resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the simulator is seeing the retina images and your device isn't than there might be a problem with case sensitivity. The simulator doesn't care but the actual devices do. Check the names of your images with and without the @2x for differences in upper and lowercases.

If this doesn't solve your problem (which would be very strange) you can automate the method by adding this to your .m file:

```
-(BOOL)retinaScreenResolution {
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
    ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
```

and call it anywhere in your code with:

```
if ([self retinaScreenResolution]) {
    //YES retina
}
else {
    //NO
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off checking `respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)` wouldn't you?  Check the selector you're actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

`imageNamed` picks the correct image.

Please try to uninstall your app from your phone, and clean and build your project before running it again on your iphone 5.

Sometimes happens that the images are not correctly refreshed i you don't make a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

from apple docs of [UIImage imageNamed:]

> If the screen has a scale of 2.0,
>   this method first searches for an image file with the same filename
>   with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is
>   button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads
>   that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object
>   to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale
>   property to 1.0.

so your assumption is wrong according to the docs

Comment: Thanks, but what am I missing? I have two files, one named file.png other named file@2x.png, I choose the file.png in storyboard. Simulator works fine, it picks the correct file, but when running on my iphone 5 it doesn't.